# How to allow access for a sql server user?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am a developer-having-to-play-admin and wish to connect to a remote sql server from my development machine using a sql server user ("op_web").

When I try to connect from vs2008 Server Explorer, I can connect to the server, but no databases are listed. If I connect using the server admin user, all databases are listed as expected.

The server is a relatively fresh install made by me.

I have

allowed for remote connections in sql server.

created the *login* op_web at server level

created a *user* at database level and assigned to *login* with same name

assigned roles to the *user* to allow for reading and writing - I have assigned no schemas and default schema for the user is dbo.

If I log on (locally at server) using sqlserver management studio/sqlserver authentication and the created login, I can display and alter table data as I would expect.

Remote access gives me no choice of databases.

Any pointers to what I might have missed?

Comment: While this is acceptable on StackOverflow, I believe you get better answers on http://serverfault.com.

Comment: Can you type in the name of a database and connect to it?

Comment: @Mehrdad - Thanks, I'll ask the question over there...

@jrummell - In Visual Studio, I get the server name listed in the dropdownlist with discovered sql server - and as mentioned, I am able to connect using windows user (adminstrator account).

Furthermore I've tried from another physical machine with same results. It doesn't smell like a firewall issue, but I've tried to disable the server firewall just in case, but that didn't fix it either. I have another database server where everything works, and I've cloned every setting user-to-user - still to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your users rights on the database.